# How to reference a type itself in Swift

Tags: ios

Here is the Objective-C version.

```
+ (NSDictionary *)modelContainerPropertyGenericClass {
    return @{
        "picIds" : String,
        "picInfos" : [WBPicture class]
    };
}
```

I did it this way but the compiler threw the error

```
static func modelContainerPropertyGenericClass() -> [String: AnyClass] {
     return [
         "picIds" : String.self,
         "picInfos" : WBPicture.self
     ]
}
```

Comment: You have an extra bracket `]` in the array constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `String` doesn't conform to `AnyObject` because it's a `struct`, and `AnyClass` is just a `typealias` for `AnyObject.Type`.

Changing the return type to `Any.Type` will also accept structs and basic types like `Int`, `Float` and `Bool`:

```
static func modelContainerPropertyGenericClass() -> [String: Any.Type] {
    return [
        "picIds": String.self,
        "picInfos": WBPicture.self
    ]
}
```

---

To keep Objective-C compatibility, replace structs and basic types with the Objective-C compatible class:

```
static func modelContainerPropertyGenericClass() -> [String: AnyClass] {
    return [
        "picIds": NSString.self,
        "picInfos": WBPicture.self,
        "int": NSNumber.self,
    ]
}
```

Comment: many thanks!,it works! By the way,I want to add this function to a protocol,and mark it as an optional one,But the compiler said Method cannot be a member of an objc protocol because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C.Is there a way to mark the function in a protocol as optional without putting objc before the protocol keyword?

Comment: Sadly no, optional protocols require Objective-C compatibility, otherwise they behave like standard Object-Oriented interfaces that require implementation. You can switch back to `AnyClass` and use Objective-C classes like `NSString` and `NSNumber` if you need it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh,I see. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
static func modelContainerPropertyGenericClass() -> [String : Any.Type] {
return ["picIds": String.self, "picInfos": WBPicture.self]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: Still doesn't compile :(

Comment: Yep, now it compiles ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, `String` is not type of `Class` it's structure. Definiton of `String` is;

```
public struct String {
    /// An empty `String`.
    public init()
}
```

You need to define it `Any.Type`

```
static func modelContainerPropertyGenericClass() -> [String : Any.Type] {
    return ["picIds": String.self, "picInfos": UITableViewCell.self]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks！ it works，but I can only mark one answer as the correct one ,sorry about that